# Is it possible to somehow use negation operator on an Angular route guard?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

In my angular 4 app I'm using **authGuard** to restrict certain pages of an app from being accessible by unregistered users.
in these specific routes I use

```
canActivate: [AuthGuard]
```

works nicely.

what I couldn't achieve is restrict access of other pages to registered users with that same **AuthGuard**. so that a registered user won't be able to navigate to **sign in**/**register** pages for example.

so logicly i just figured i'd negate that result with **!** operator on the **AuthGuard**

```
{
    path: 'sign-in',
    component: SignInComponent,
    canActivate: [!AuthGuard]
}
```

but this approach throws an error

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Token must be defined!

I think creating another route guard just to return the opposite result is a bad practice.

Any way to make this simple approach work?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can try

```
canActivate: [{provide: AuthGuard: useFactory: () => new AuthGuard(false)}]
```

and use the value passed to the constructor in `AuthGuard`